# a tag breaks in two lines in chrome, why ?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Im expierencing a kindda funny problem - If you take a look at this page: http://www.cinemaxx.dk/koebenhavn/events/date-night/

And look at the breadcrumb, then the link/word "Date Night" breaks in two lines, however, there not defined a fixed width of the element, and it is set to display:inline-block

It works fine in FF, IE, Safari, but not in Chrome, and I cant figure out why, so hoping for a bit help? :)

Comment: It seems the computed width is **calculated before a:after class is applied** for padding-left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

css to your link, I try and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this *style:*

```
nav.breadcrumb a:last-child:after {
    content: '';
}
```

It should work fine then.

Note: if you want to remove the last *star* , use [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) with [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%3Alast-child) selector.